# CORS issue with okta setup seemingly correctly?

Tags: javascript, cors, okta

As you can see from the first image below, I am having some cors issue. I believe I have set everything up correctly. I have the correct issuer url, and localhost:3000 is a trusted origin in Okta. However, the error contradicts that CORS is setup correctly. Maybe, I have forgotten a step or something.

a little code from the javascript sdk

```
formSignIn.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData(formSignIn);
    let credentials = {}
    credentials["username"] = formData.get("email");
    credentials["password"] = formData.get("password");

    authClient.signIn(credentials).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        authClient.token.getWithRedirect({
          sessionToken: res.sessionToken,
          responseType: 'id_token',
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

My error message in the chrome console. Seemings says the urls in my okta configurations are not a valid origin
[image: My error message in the javascript console. Seemings says the urls in my okta configurations are not a valid origin]
a screenshot of localhost:3000 being setup correctly for CORS in the okta dashboard
[image: a screenshot of localhost:3000 being setup correctly for CORS in the okta dashboard]
A Screenshot of the issuer url assign by okta being exactly what was shown in the first image
[image: A Screenshot of the issuer url assign by okta being exactly what was shown in the first image.]

Comment: It's the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request that is failing. Check your browser's _Network_ console for any error messages in the response

Comment: You need to take a closer look at the [documentation](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#signinoptions). The `signIn` method does not appear to accept `FormData`. You need to send an object with `username` and `password` properties